# how to follow rest constraint HATEOAS principle in .net

Tags: .net, rest, hateoas

i tried to create one example with rest architecture. i following 3 constraint but i can't follow the fourth hypermedia(hateoas).i returing in json format.json didn't support links right.

```
 {"attributecollection":{"Soid":"123","BUCODE":"syn123","ClientCode":"att12"}
```

so for following hateoas what i want to add links in json ?.so for that i want to do some customize code for adding link.is there any tool available that create links.i can't find any good simple example that follow hateoas.some presentation i found but that in java..so can anyone provide any link or example that will follow hateoas in json in .net. Advance Thanks